# Is it Pythonic to use objects wherever possible?

Tags: python, oop

Newbie Python question here - I am writing a little utility in Python to do disk space calculations when given the attributes of 2 different files.

Should I create a 'file' class with methods appropriate to the conversion and then create each file as an instance of that class? I'm pretty new to Python, but ok with Perl, and I believe that in Perl (I may be wrong, being self-taught), from the examples that I have seen, that most Perl is not OO.

Background info - These are IBM z/OS (mainframe) data sets, and when given the allocation attributes for a file on a specific disk type and file organisation (it's block size) and then given the allocation parameters for a different disk type & organisation, the space requirements can vary enormously.

Comment: I wonder if this is a more appropriate question for programmers.stackexchange, but I'm not sure.

Comment: He is writing a utility to calculate disk space..and in python you can do it withn a mere 60 lines of code..could you explain why a class is necessary in that case!?

Comment: Wikipedia calls Python "multi-paradigm" which indicates to me that you can largely avoid anything OO if you don't like it.

Comment: Languages themselves are not object-oriented. Various languages have features that make it easier to program in an object-oriented fashion, however.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that vast majority of code I have written has been in IBM Mainframe Assembler language - it doesn't have many features to make OO programming easier... :-)

Comment: Not *every* language has such features :)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.l I wasn't really asking about OO design in general, just if it was Pythonic to use an object if I could and yes - this isn't a concrete coding problem so perhaps not the right place to ask. As the question was about real things (well, as real as a file can be), then I've decided to make them objects.

Comment: Related: [Stop Writing Classes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o9pEzgHorH0)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Definition nitpicking preface: Everything in Python is technically an object, even functions and numbers. I'm going to assume you mean classes vs. functions in your question.*

Actually I think one of the great things about Python is that it doesn't embrace classes for absolutely everything as some other languages (e.g., Java and C#).

It's perfectly acceptable in Python (and the built-in modules do this a lot) to define module level functions rather than encapsulating all logic in objects.

That said, classes do have their place, for example when you perform multiple actions on a single piece of data, and especially when these actions change the data and you want to keep its state encapsulated.

Answer (score 2):

For Your Question and you requirements ..a short answer is "No"

Answer (score 0):

1. The use of objects is not in itself "object oriented". Functional programming uses objects, too, just not in the same way. Python can be used in a very FP way, even though Python uses objects heavily behind the scenes.
2. Overuse of primitives can be a problem, but it's impossible to say whether that applies to your case without more data.

I think of OO as an interface design approach: If you are creating tools that are straightforward to interact with (and substitutable) as objects with predictable methods, then by all means, create objects. But if the interactions are straightforward to describe with module-level functions, then don't try too hard to engineer your code into classes.

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost - Pythonic is a term that needs to disappear, preferably with everyone who uses it. It doesn't mean anything and it's used by people who can't use reason to justify anything, so they need a mandatory term to justify their nonsense.

But to the point you never HAVE to use object oriented concepts in your software development, as everything OOP can as easily be written with functions and solid spaghetti stringers. But the question is - do use of objects makes sense in my  solution?

To understand when and how to use it, you have to ask what exactly is object oriented programming. And this was already very well explained in very old, but also free, book called `Thinking in java` which I consider to be the 101 bible of thinking on OO terms. I strongly urge you to grab a [free copy](http://www.mindview.net/Books/TIJ/) and read couple of first chapters.

Because if you don't understand the object oriented approach, how can you apply it properly? When you do - then when to use it, or not use it, becomes clear, because you can clearly translate real life items and interactions into abstract objects. And this is the guideline - when the translation of given action, item or data to OOP model is straightforward and logical - then you should do it.